Change Smart Search results template layout
I have 2 layouts in my template:

default (which is indeed set as default)
home


For some reason Smart Search results use the home layout.
How can I switch it to use default layout?

For most things you would nominate the template style you want to use in the menu item (see screenshot).
If it's not working on a smart search item, you could try doing a duplicate style of the default layout and nominate it as the specific template to use.

Thanks, that works. Still no idea why the default style isn't used normally, but I guess it's a workaround, I don't need anything else with this hell of a system, TBH.
